# How to create custom Sling content distribution tool for sending JSON from one AEM instance to another?

Tags: json, aem, sling

I have two AEM instances. I need to use custom Sling Content Distribution for sending JSON file from Instance-1 to Instance-2. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using a tag. `Distribution` is reserved for statistical distributions.